# NextGEN gallery slideshow giving error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slideshow, nextgen-gallery

I've installed the latest version of [NextGEN gallery](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) (`version 2.0.40`). All other options like **Basic Thumbnails**, **Basic ImageBrowser**, **Basic SinglePic** are working fine but when I tried to create a **Basic Slideshow** then it's not working! I can only see the slideshow loading icon but no slideshow images. This is how I called the gallery to a page:

```
<?php echo nggShowSlideshow(1,300,200); ?>
```

I've check the **error console** & its shows following error:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).nggShowSlideshow is not a function


timeout: 10000      });
```

I've searched for solution of this issue & some people suggested to change **this**:

```
jQuery(function($){
        jQuery('#<?php echo_h($anchor); ?>').nggShowSlideshow({
            //code here
        });
```

**with this**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery('#<?php echo_h($anchor); ?>').nggShowSlideshow({
            //code here
        });
```

but it didn't worked for me! By the way, my **Wordpress version 3.7.1**.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda odd to answer my own question, but I want to state my findings here so that it might be helpful to others!

What I've figured out is, `footer` was missing in my `page-templates`! As most of the **wordpress** plugin's `javascript` files are being called through `footer` so if you miss `<?php get_footer(); ?>` in your `page-templates` then you may get such error like `TypeError: jQuery(...).nggShowSlideshow is not a function`! I've missed footer while working with custom `page-templates`.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old but I think it is necessary to add a small remark to the answer:

Don't call get_footer() if you don't need the footer. This function adds the footer-template to the output. I think there may be a good reason why there isn't a get_footer()-call in your template (or another template).

Basically, you are missing wp_footer(). Calling wp_footer() at the end of your body-tag us doing the job:

```
<body>
...
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```